# Step down into livingroom. Too tall? split in two?

Tags: stairs

There is a step down from the main level to the livingroom level. It's a bit over 8" I think it's too much - for me anyway. I am considering adding a second step, which would make each riser approx. 4". Does that make sense? Or should I just learn to live with the bigger step?

Answer (score 4):

First Google [result](https://www.stairsupplies.com/resources/stair-design/high-individual-stairs/) says:

> In the United States, the step height standard should be between 7 or 7 ¾ inches at the most, and no less than 4 inches.

which I can't cite as code but which matches many other things I've read, including here on DIY SE.

So if it is really a bit over 8", you want to split it *exactly in half*. That is both to make each step over 4" and also because just as important as the height is consistency. When you put your foot down on the first step, you *expect* that the second step will be the same height. Doing this can be a little tricky as you need to take carpet/pad/tile/etc. into account when figuring out the height.

Shorter steps are generally going to be safer, but as you can see from the recommendations, for any given distance (until you get to a several step stairway) there is generally only 1 or 2 combinations that will work:

- < 8" = 1 step
- 8" - 12" = 2 steps
- 12" - 16" = 2 or 3 steps
- 16" - 20" = 3 or 4 steps

As you get to a larger stairway, larger steps (i.e., ~ 7") make a lot more sense. Once you are going up or down a couple of feet, you are really "climbing the stairs" and 7" is fine. But when it is less than a foot, it is more like moving between parts of a room and shorter distances make sense.

I've actually never really understood the point of sunken living rooms. For the able-bodied is a minor inconvenience for a minor benefit. For anyone in a wheelchair, on crutches or even just a little unsteady climbing stairs it is a major challenge, without the benefit that a full stairway gives of a an entire *additional* level of the house. In the house where I (mostly) grew up, we had one large "family room" that was two steps down. But it actually made sense because it was on the same slab as the garage (the garage was only accessible from the outside) with bedrooms above, while the living room/dining room/kitchen/den were all above the basement. But typical sunken living rooms that I have seen are on the same section of the house (either slab or above a basement) as the non-sunken rooms next to them - i.e., a "design" feature rather than based on functional reasons.

Comment: Agree. One traditional way of relating rise and run is to have them add up to about 18”, so your tread would be comfortable at 14”. (I know that sounds big, compared to ‘regular’ stairs, but you can either trust me or do the research.)

Comment: One other option is raise the level of the living room by 1" or raise it by the full amount and get rid of the sunken feature.

Comment: Agree with @AloysiusDefenestrate that for a very short 4" rise, the run needs to be fairly long. OP should look around town for monuments, government buildings, etc that have short rise steps and note how long the run is. Short rise and short run is _very_ awkwardly uncomfortable to walk up and down.

Comment: I am going to raise the level by 1.5" (subfloor and engineered hardwood) - so I'll end up with a 7" step

Comment: Another question on this project. I am adding another 5/8" of plywood. This not only raises the level but also gives me more options for the floor. The current underlayment is particleboard. Below that is plywood. Both are 5/8". So with my new 5/8" plywood, I am screwing through almost 2" of material. My plan is to use 3.5" screws. Then on top of that will be 5/8 engineered hardwood. So in the end there will be 2.5" of flooring involved. Should I be concerned? About the weight for instance?

Comment: Weight could be an issue. I have absolutely no idea. And for anyone to possibly have an idea, they would need to know more about the structure - e.g., size of joists, supports, etc. Which all should be a new question.